# To Necro or Repost?

Tags: discussion

I had an idea that ended up being similar to [this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31046/portals-to-parallel-earths-economic-effects?__=954073532), as well as a bunch of starting ideas that weren't mentioned. However, I'm hesitant to just add an answer to that question, since

1) it's 4 years old at this point, so this would be a thread necro of the highest caliber, and

2) none of the previous answers are (in my opinion) very helpful at all. Most didn't understand the question, and those who did basically threw up their hands and decided that it was moot. If I add to the discussion, I'm worried that it'll get lost in what's already there, and my odds of having my (and the original asker's) question answer will be slim.

Ordinarily, neither of these 2 reasons on their own would be grounds to ask the question again, but I'm wondering if both together might justify it. I'd link to the original question, and hopefully I could phrase the question a bit better, add my new insights, and see if the community has anything to add since 4 years ago.

Is that the right way to go about it, or does forum etiquette force me to just revive the old thread?

Comment: Do you have a question or an answer?

Comment: I have a question, which happens to be very similar to the linked question. In thinking about the question myself, I've also come up with a few relevant answers, but it's one of those questions where there are many possible answers, and I'd like to find others.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a forum, there is no room for new questions within old ones. If you feel like you have a valuable answer to the old question by all means provide an answer. If you want an answer to your question ask it. If there is a chance that someone will mistake the old question as a duplicate of the new one, address why you feel your new question is different. If it is not different and you just want new answers then I don't believe there is much option.

Comment: Exactly. There are even badges for excavating ancient queries and posting new answers!   (Mind you, there's no good reason not to necro a good thread in a discussion forum.  The prohibition against that is just senseless.)

Answer (score 4):

The site has changed over the years.  That original question is now too broad (very much too broad) and I've voted to close it as such.  However, to address your specific points.

1) The age of a question is irrelevant.  To post a new question you would need to justify how that old question was *obsolete.*  On this site, "obsolete" is a big word and remarkably difficult to justify.

2) The fact that you don't like the answers or feel that they were inadequate is a great reason to post a new answer, but a lousy reason to ask a new question.  Were this a question that fit the rules as we have them today, then I would have happily posted a fat bounty to bring attention back to the question.  Bounties are, perhaps, the best way to draw attention to questions that need better, fresher, or simply new answers.

Comment: Alright, then if I can ask something more specific: if I wanted that question answered (and I don't know how to make the question much less broad), what would be the best way to get that done? Add a new answer? Or does the fact that this question is now too broad mean that I should just repost it on a more discussion-oriented forum? (If it's the latter, I'd appreciate a recommendation for a different site to try. I just want this question answered).

Comment: I'd use a discussion-oriented forum. I don't know of any because I don't use them. Regrettably, part of the problem is that Stack Exchange is intended to answer specific questions that address specific problems. "A rung on my wooden ladder broke, what glue should I use to fix it?" is perfect for SE. Asking about global market effects (which has been tried a number of times) usually indicates the OP hasn't thought through the question or is looking for insight to help them ask a more specific question. Unfortunately, it's the kind of insight college courses were intended to provide.

Comment: BTW, I've taken college courses in economics.  When you say, "I just want this question answered," what you're telling me is, "I don't understand what to ask" because the only way to describe global economics is by writing a book.  Usually a textbook.

Comment: Oh, if your only hangup about this is the "global economics" part of the question, as it happens that's where my question and the original diverge. I'm less concerned with large-scale economic effects than with specific, useful technological applications. I can infer the economic ramifications of the technologies from there. Does that change your answer?

Comment: :-)  In regard to this post, no, but in regard to your desire to post, yes.  If you can ask about specific economic effects (you need to define the specific economic conditions!) then fire away.  My basic rule: be as specific as you can, you're welcome to ask more questions, but leaving the fist question ambiguous in the hope of a sweeping answer that addresses all your concerns will frequently get it closed.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have a better idea now of how to make my question different and specific. I'll ask it on this site after all.

Comment: @GiladM --- Re worldbuilding forums, look for my answer to this question: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/132660/worldbuilding-forum-or-other-conversational-place/132662#132662